# Removing Bullets from ASP.NET Master Page Using CSS

Tags: html, asp.net, css

This is homework.  Here is the code for the navigation menu on the Master page, and I want to remove the bullets from the list:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="#FFFFFF">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/> 
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Rating.aspx" Text="Rating"/> 
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Favorite.aspx" Text="Favorite"/> 
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Default.aspx" Text="Administrator" /> 

                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
```

Since ID="NavigationMenu", shouldn't this CSS syntax remove the bullets?

```
ul#NavigationMenu {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;

}
```

This is the rendered HTML:

```
<a href="#NavigationMenu_SkipLink" style="position:absolute;left:-10000px;top:auto;width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden;">Skip Navigation Links</a><div class="menu" id="NavigationMenu">
    <ul class="level1">
        <li><a class="level1" href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="Rating.aspx">Rating</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="Favorite.aspx">Favorite</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="Admin/Default.aspx">Administrator</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><a id="NavigationMenu_SkipLink"></a>
```

Comment: Please show the **rendered HTML**, not the server-side ASP.NET control markup. And no, your CSS is not guranteed to work because ASP.NET Web Controls mangle the `id=""` attributes, nor does it generate 'clean' markup.

Comment: I added the rendered HTML.

Comment: Change your CSS to ul.level1 instead of ul#NavigationMenu

Comment: To this? 
ul.level1#NavigationMenu {
}

Comment: Nope just "ul.level1"  or alternatively just ".level1" but this will apply it to all elements of that class.  ul tells it to only apply to ul tags with a class attribute set to "level1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you are having  is that the ID gets altered from what you type in the ASPX file when it makes it to the HTML page.  ASP.Net does this automatically for various reasons including nested controls.  You can check the ID that shows up in the HTML by viewing the source of the HTML and seeing the ID applied to the list tag.

Option 1:
You could alter your CSS to use the ID you see in the source.  This is not a good option because you need to check the ID on the web page every time you want to apply a style.  Styles should not be applied to the dynamically created name unless there is no other way around it.

Option 2:
Because the ID should be unique on the page, there is no need to qualify the CSS with the ul tag.  It will be applied to the element with the ID you specify (note comment about changing ID).  Erase the "ul" from the CSS and just use #ID_OF_TAG if you are applying CSS with the ID.

Option 3:
THIS IS THE BEST OPTION.  Apply the CSS using a class rather than connecting with the ID.  With the class, use the '.ClassName' notation.  A class name will not be changed by ASP.Net and will be portable if the control in question is used within another control.  The CSS class name is typically applied in the "CssClass" attribute of ASP.Net controls. Using the CssClass, it is appropriate to use the ul.MY_CLASS_NAME notation since the class name could be shared by a variety of tags.

----UPDATE------

After seeing the additions with the HTML the problem you are having is that the ID for the menu is being put on the DIV tag instead of the UL tag.  You will need to set the CSS in definition for "ul.level1".

------HTML SAMPLE ------
Here is your HTML with CSS added in that removes the bullet style.  I have tested this and the bullets do not show up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
        ul.level1 {
            list-style-type:none;
            }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#NavigationMenu_SkipLink" style="position:absolute;left:-10000px;top:auto;width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden;">Skip Navigation Links</a><div class="menu" id="NavigationMenu">
    <ul class="level1">
        <li><a class="level1" href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="Rating.aspx">Rating</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="Favorite.aspx">Favorite</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="Admin/Default.aspx">Administrator</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><a id="NavigationMenu_SkipLink"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

If the CSS properties are not being applied as expected it is probably one of two things.  It could be that the CSS is in a file that is not being imported.  I don't expect that to be the case.  Second is the CSS class could be getting overwritten by another class.  You could change the name of the class to test this.

Comment: That is the last resort.  If nothing else works you could try to apply the style inline by adding the Style="" attribute to the line items.  I think it can, but am not positive that the bullet style is defined at the LI level. I didn't add this option to the answer because I wasn't sure.  It's better to have the styles in classes rather than inline in most cases.  But there are exceptions such as when designing HTML for email in which case it is more likely that CSS in classes and header definitions will be ignored.

Comment: I deleted a lot of the other css, which I copied from another student, and it worked.  Using someone else's code and then changing it always messes me up.  It's better to start from scratch.  Thank you for your time and effort!!! :)

Comment: Glad I can help... Cut and paste programming is a valuable tool nowadays so learning what to do to troubleshoot it and work out problems like this is something you will want in your back pocket.  Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: How do you create space in between ul items?  Right now they're all smooshed together.
ul.level1 {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: "Adobe Garamond Pro Bold"
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42686/discussion-between-grafica-and-racernerd)